# symfony sonata - object to string

Tags: symfony

I've a entity (many to many) who match with my product entity.
I need to connect with images with a wiew but
i have the error could not convert to _string !!!`enter code here`

```
 $showMapper
        ->with('PRODUCT DESCRIPTION', array('class' => 'col-md-7'))
        ->add('name')
        ->add('country')
        ->add('descriptionshortnat', null, array('label' => 'Description short (national)'))
        ->add('descriptionlongnat', null, array('label' => 'Description long (national)'))
        ->add('descriptionshorten', null, array('label' => 'Description short (english)'))
        ->add('descriptionlongen', null, array('label' => 'Description long (english)'))
        ->add('created')
        ->add('updated')
        ->end()

        ->with('PICTURES', array('class' => 'col-md-5'))
        ->add('image', 'string' , array("template"=>"AdminBundle::Admin/list_types/image10.html.twig"))
        ->end()
```

and my twig code for the view

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
<a href="{{ asset('uploads/documents/') }}{{ value|nl2br }}"><img class="admin-list-preview" src="{{ asset('uploads/documents/') }}{{ value|nl2br }}"/></a>
{% endblock %}
```

and my entity image

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * Image
 */
class Image
{
/**
 * @var int
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @var type
 */
private $file;

/**
 * @var type
 */
private $fichier;



/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}


public function __toString()
{
return $this->fichier;    
}


public function getname()
{
return $this->fichier;
}




/**
 * Set fichier
 *
 * @param string $fichier
 *
 * @return Image
 */
public function setFichier($fichier)
{
    $this->fichier = $fichier;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get fichier
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFichier()
{
    return $this->fichier;

}



/**
 * Set file
 *
 * @param string $file
 * @return Image
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file=null)
{
    $this->file = $file;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get file
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}





public function upload() {
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if(null === $this->getFile())
    {
        return;
    }

    // we use the original file name here but you should
    // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

    // move takes the target directory and target filename as params
    $this->getFile()->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
        $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName()
    );

    // set the path property to the path where you've saved the file
    $this->setFichier($this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName());

    // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
    $this->setFile(null);






}




public function removeUpload() {
     if($file = $this->getAbsolutePath())
    {
        if(is_file($file))
        {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }

}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->getFichier()
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->getFichier();

}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->getFichier()
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getFichier();


}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded
    // documents should be saved
    return __DIR__.'/../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();

}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return 'uploads/documents';

  }






}
```

and finally my doctrine for products is

```
AdminBundle\Entity\Products:
type: entity
table: null
sortable: true
repositoryClass: AdminBundle\Repository\ProductsRepository
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 255
    descriptionshortnat:
        type: text
        length: 500
        nullable: true
    descriptionlongnat:
        type: text
        length: 5000
        nullable: true
    descriptionshorten:
        type: text
        length: 500
        nullable: true
    descriptionlongen:
        type: text
        length: 5000
        nullable: true
    created:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
        gedmo:
          timestampable:
            on: create
    updated:
        type: datetime
        nullable: true
        gedmo:
          timestampable:
            on: update
lifecycleCallbacks:
  prePersist: [ setCreatedAtValue,setUpdatedAtValue ]
  preUpdate: [ setUpdatedAtValue ]
manyToOne:
    country:
        targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Country
        joinColumn:
            name: country
            referencedColumnName: id
        nullable: TRUE
    category:
        targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Category
        joinColumn:
            name: category
            referencedColumnName: id
        nullable: TRUE
    preservation:
        targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Preservation
        joinColumn:
            name: preservation
            referencedColumnName: id
        nullable: TRUE
    population:
        targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Population
        joinColumn:
            name: population
            referencedColumnName: id
        nullable: TRUE
    innovation:
        targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Innovation
        joinColumn:
            name: innovation
            referencedColumnName: id
        nullable: TRUE
    timeframe:
        targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Timeframe
        joinColumn:
            name: timeframe
            referencedColumnName: id
        nullable: TRUE
    component:
        targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Component
        joinColumn:
            name: component
            referencedColumnName: id
        nullable: TRUE
manyToMany:
    contact:
        targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Contact
        joinTable:
            name: allproducts
            joinColumns:
                products:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                contact:
                    referencedColumnName: id
    organisation:
        targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Organisation
        joinTable:
            name: allorganisation
            joinColumns:
                product:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                organisation:
                    referencedColumnName: id
    competition:
        targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Competition
        joinTable:
            name: allcompetition
            joinColumns:
                competition:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                product:
                    referencedColumnName: id
    image:
        targetEntity: AdminBundle\Entity\Image
        joinTable:
            name: allpictures
            joinColumns:
                product:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                image:
                    referencedColumnName: id
```

I see that the connection match is the listmapper, but i need to see a picture, not the name of the picture

thanks a lot !!

Comment: you should format your post properly, parts of the code falls outside of the code blocks

Comment: also,   i dont see anything beeing outputted in your twig ?

Comment: {% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    <a href="{{ asset('uploads/documents/') }}{{ value|nl2br }}"><img class="admin-list-preview" src="{{ asset('uploads/documents/') }}{{ value|nl2br }}"/></a>
{% endblock %}

Comment: i don't know what to do ?

Comment: do a {{ dump(value) }}   in your twig,   and post the output, (formatted in your question)

Comment: No route found for "GET /uploads/documents/%3Cscript%3E%20Sfdump%20=%20window.Sfdump%20%7C%7C%20(function%20(doc)%20%7B%20var%20refStyle%20=%20doc.createElement('style'),%20rxEsc%20=%20/([.*+"

Comment: what now suddenly it cant find a route ?    what is beeing outputted by the twig dump,   also,   pls edit your question, and post it there, so you can properly format it

Comment: -image: PersistentCollection {#594}
    -created: DateTime {#516
      +"date": "2017-03-02 08:10:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Europe/Paris"
    }
    -updated: DateTime {#517
      +"date": "2017-05-18 11:02:01.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Europe/Paris"
    }
    -partner: null
  }
  -association: array:19 [ …19]
  -em: EntityManager {#228 …11}
  -backRefFieldName: null
  -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#587 …}
  -isDirty: false
  #collection: ArrayCollection {#595
    -elements: []
  }
  #initialized: false
}

Comment: PLEASE post the above in your question, so that you can FORMAT it,   and i can actually READ it ...